# NestJS class-validator validate array of numbers in form data

Tags: node.js, express, validation, nestjs, class-variables

How can I handle the validation of an array of numbers in form data?
Because I am passing data in a form-data format, I can't validate an array of numbers Actually, I don't know how to do it.

[image]

This is my **CreatePostDto**:

```
export class CreatePostDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(3)
  title: string;

  @ApiProperty({ type: 'string', format: 'binary' })
  thumbnail: any;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(20)
  @MaxLength(300)
  description: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(20)
  body: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsNumberString({}, { each: true })
  tags: number[];

  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsNumberString({}, { each: true })
  categories: number[];

  @IsBooleanString()
  published: boolean;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

A decision:
https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/454

Short answer:

```
@IsNumber({},{each: true})
numbers: number[];
```